# What is a good .Net library for Windows User Administration?

Tags: .net-2.0, ldap, adsi, user-administration

We have a company intranet with staff management functions. I would like to begin automating setup of new staff members, e.g. creating Windows accounts for them, creating their home folders, setting up shares, and the like. When a staff member leaves the company I would like to automatically remove their user.

I have been battling to find any good references or libraries for administering users using .Net 2.0.

I am willing to write ADSI code or even WMI code, but need some sample code to kick start the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the following sample on the Code Project, showing [how to add a new user using DirectoryServices](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/addnewuser.aspx):

```
private void AddUser(string strDoamin, string strLogin, string strPwd)
{
  DirectoryEntry obDirEntry = null;
  try
  {
    obDirEntry = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + strDoamin);
    DirectoryEntries entries = obDirEntry.Children;
    DirectoryEntry obUser = entries.Add(strLogin, "User");
    obUser.Properties["FullName"].Add("Amigo");
    object obRet = obUser.Invoke("SetPassword", strPwd);
    obUser.CommitChanges();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Trace.Warn(ex.Message);
  }
}
```

But a real breakthrough has come via me signing up on [Safari Books Online](http://safaribooksonline.com/), and discovering a book there called "The .NET Developer's Guide to Directory Services Programming" - ISBN 10: 0-321-35017-0; ISBN 13: 978-0-321-35017-6

This book seems tailor made for my dilemma as it explains all the basics of programming directory services, then gives specific examples for adding users, setting permissions, etc.

Comment: Watch out though - the WinNT:// provider is only good for local server user accounts - it will *NOT* work for Active Directory accounts. For those, you'll need to use the LDAP:// provider, which is also extensively documented in Joe Kaplan's excellent book.